# How to get number of npm modules installed except dev dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install, node-modules

Is there an NPM CLI command I can use to get the number of NPM Modules installed in my package, excluding those that are only Dev Dependencies? `npm ls` shows all of the packages, but it doesn't say how many or which are Dev Dependencies and which aren't. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
npm ls --only=dev
npm ls --only=prod
```

For this purpose, you can also do

```
npm ls --dev
```

or

```
npm ls --prod
```

Pipe it out to grep to count:

```
npm ls --depth=0 --dev | grep "\-\-" -c
```

Comment: is there any way to number them?

Comment: You could maybe do a npm ls --depth=0 --dev, to list only top level dev dependencies?

Comment: `grep -n` can number them.

Answer (score 13):

Try this

```
  npm ls --only=prod --depth=0 | wc -l
```

Now subtract by 2 whatever you get. 
*( -1 is for last line and another  -1 is for first line where `npm ls` shows the directory.)*

(Use `git-bash` if you're using `Windows`.)

**Demo**

[image]

I got `14`, it means I've `12` dependency.

Comment: Also `npm ls --only=prod --depth=0 | Measure-Object -Line` in PowerShell

Comment: Might also be smart to remove deduped and type dependencies:
`| Select-String -Patter "^(?!.*(@types|deduped)).*$"`